# Light Shader Attribute Inputs

Tags: lighting

On Blender 3.2.1

[image]

For light objects it seems that both Object Info and Attribute nodes return 0s, e.g.:

[image: Using Object Info node]

or

[image: Using Attribute node]

with object panel:

[image: Custom Properties on object]

Both act as if the Vector input is receiving 0,0,0

Is there any way to get attributes from the object into the material shader for a light?

Intentions:

I'm trying to achieve is a hard-edge spotlight with some specifically programmed parameters (i.e. to emulate a Source 4). This is possible if we make a unique copy of the shader for each light (as the parameters can then be stored inside the shader). Ideally, I'd like to have one shader and store these parameters in the light object itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? That attribute are you trying to get? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I added my intentions at the bottom (took a while because Stack Exchange was down when I tried last time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this not seems possible at the time. The [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html) states: "Currently, attributes are not supported in shaders used for the World or Light Objects."